# NetBeans | При подключении по FTP выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp

При подключении PHP проекта с удалённого сервера по FTP  выдаёт ошибку:

Unknown host **** invalid IPv6 address

Изменял конфиги, не помогло. Как исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: Приведите пример URL

Answer (score 1):

в имени узла уберите ftp:// и напишите адрес просто через www. 
меня спасло

Comment: Это только если узел с поддоменом www существует. На мой взгляд префикс www. - атавизм